# rosmake tum_ardrone

Tags: ros, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey All, I am having some trouble compiling the tum_ardrone package.  It gets to the last step when I get this error,

```
  SIMD support:
  mmx mmxext sse sse2 sse3
  
  Missing SIMD support for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu:
```

Does this just mean that I can't compile it on a 64 bit machine?  Or do I need a different type of linux?   I am currently running Ubuntu 13.02.

---

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89181/rosmake-tum_ardrone/) by [juicedatom](https://answers.ros.org/users/6601/juicedatom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-09**:
Is that really 13.02? please give the full context of the error.  What SIMD instruction sets do you think are available on your machine?

**Comment by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on 2013-10-31**:
I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error log is this

SIMD support:
mmx mmxext sse sse2 sse3

Missing SIMD support for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu:

-g -Wall -Wextra -pipe -ggdb -fPIC -mmmx -msse -msse -msse2 -msse3 -pthread
-ltiff -ljpeg -lpng -lpng -lGLU -lGL -lrt -L -lX11 -lXext -pthread
Generating config... configuration unchanged
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
cd build && export CPATH=../../TooN/include && make
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/libcvd/build' g++ -O3 -I. -I.  -INONE/include -g  -Wall -Wextra -pipe -ggdb -fPIC -mmmx -msse -msse -msse2 -msse3 -pthread -c progs/video_play_source.cc -o progs/video_play_source.o progs/video_play_source.cc: In function ‘void play(std::string)’: progs/video_play_source.cc:200:17: error: there are no arguments to ‘usleep’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘usleep’ must be available [-fpermissive] progs/video_play_source.cc:200:17: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated) progs/video_play_source.cc: In instantiation of ‘void play(std::string) [with C = CVD::Rgb<unsigned char>; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’: progs/video_play_source.cc:241:30:   required from here progs/video_play_source.cc:200:4: error: ‘usleep’ was not declared in this scope In file included from ./cvd/internal/convert_pixel_types.h:27:0, from ./cvd/image_convert.h:25, from ./cvd/colourspacebuffer.h:27, from ./cvd/videosource.h:13, from progs/video_play_source.cc:38: ./cvd/internal/scalar_convert.h: At global scope: ./cvd/internal/scalar_convert.h:112:21: warning: ‘CVD::Pixel::Internal::init_float_for_byte’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable] ./cvd/internal/scalar_convert.h:113:21: warning: ‘CVD::Pixel::Internal::init_double_for_byte’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable] make[3]: *** [progs/video_play_source.o] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/libcvd/build'
make[2]: *** [libcvd_built] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/libcvd' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty'
make: *** [all] Error 2

The solution is to add

```
#include <unistd.h> // it defines usleep()
```

to

```
/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/libcvd/build/progs/video_play_source.cc
/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/libcvd/installfiles/progs/video_play_source.cc
```

This compilation issue is used to be a warning, nowadays compilers become more strict, so it is an error now.

*EDIT
Not really a general solution, there are many other errors occurred after.

```
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/../DroneController.h:27,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIProcedure.h:26,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIFlyTo.h:25,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIFlyTo.cpp:21:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/debug.hh:100:33: note: ‘template<class P> void TooN::Internal::debug_initialize(P*, int)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/drone_gui
  In file included from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/TooN.h:250:0,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/so3.h:33,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/se3.h:33,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/../DroneController.h:27,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIProcedure.h:26,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIFlyTo.h:25,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIFlyTo.cpp:21:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/allocator.hh: In instantiation of ‘TooN::Internal::StackOrHeap<Size, Precision, false>::StackOrHeap() [with int Size = 3; Precision = int]’:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/allocator.hh:105:43:   required from ‘TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<Size, Precision>::VectorAlloc() [with int Size = 3; Precision = int]’
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/vbase.hh:96:16:   required from ‘TooN::Internal::GenericVBase<Size, Precision, Stride, Mem>::GenericVBase() [with int Size = 3; Precision = int; int Stride = 1; Mem = TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<3, int>]’
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/vbase.hh:72:12:   required from ‘TooN::Internal::VBase::VLayout<Size, Precision>::VLayout() [with int Size = 3; Precision = int]’
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/vector.hh:143:17:   required from ‘TooN::Vector<Size, Precision, Base>::Vector() [with int Size = 3; Precision = int; Base = TooN::Internal::VBase]’
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/make_vector.hh:34:24:   required from ‘TooN::Vector<3, Precision> TooN::makeVector(const Precision&, const Precision&, const Precision&) [with Precision = int]’
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/../DroneController.h:55:59:   required from here
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/allocator.hh:58:3: warning: ‘debug_initialize’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
  In file included from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/TooN.h:255:0,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/so3.h:33,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/se3.h:33,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/../DroneController.h:27,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIProcedure.h:26,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIFlyTo.h:25,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/KI/KIFlyTo.cpp:21:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/debug.hh:100:33: note: ‘template<class P> void TooN::Internal::debug_initialize(P*, int)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
  make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/build'
  [ 55%] Built target drone_gui
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/drone_autopilot
  make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/build'
  [ 55%] Built target drone_autopilot
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/build'
  make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone'
```

*Edit

To solve above problem do the following
In tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/internal/allocator.hh,
add at the begining,

```
#include “debug.hh”
```

In tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/internal/debug.hh,
add at the beginning,

```
#ifndef DEBUG_HH
#define DEBUG_HH
```

add at the end,

```
#endif
```

this solution taken form [here](http://ewokrampage.wordpress.com/troubleshooting-faq/).

However further compilation generated the following errors

```
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/Map.h:18,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.h:20,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.cc:2:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/operators.hh:77:84: warning: ‘v3BestMean.TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StaticSizedAllocator<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StackOrHeap<3, double, false>::my_data[2ul]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.cc:1110:13: note: ‘v3BestMean.TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StaticSizedAllocator<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StackOrHeap<3, double, false>::my_data[2ul]’ was declared here
  In file included from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/TooN.h:267:0,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/so3.h:33,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/se3.h:33,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/Map.h:18,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.h:20,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.cc:2:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/operators.hh:77:84: warning: ‘v3BestMean.TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StaticSizedAllocator<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StackOrHeap<3, double, false>::my_data[1ul]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.cc:1110:13: note: ‘v3BestMean.TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StaticSizedAllocator<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StackOrHeap<3, double, false>::my_data[1ul]’ was declared here
  In file included from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/TooN.h:267:0,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/so3.h:33,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/se3.h:33,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/Map.h:18,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.h:20,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.cc:2:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/operators.hh:77:84: warning: ‘v3BestMean.TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StaticSizedAllocator<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StackOrHeap<3, double, false>::my_data[0ul]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.cc:1110:13: note: ‘v3BestMean.TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StaticSizedAllocator<3, double>::<anonymous>.TooN::Internal::StackOrHeap<3, double, false>::my_data[0ul]’ was declared here
  In file included from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.h:21:0,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/Tracker.h:24,
                   from /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/Tracker.cc:3:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/KeyFrame.h: In member function ‘void Tracker::TrackMap()’:
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/KeyFrame.h:43:8: warning: ‘m.Measurement::Source’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  /home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/src/stateestimation/PTAM/Tracker.cc:842:19: note: ‘m.Measurement::Source’ was declared here
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/drone_stateestimation
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[4]: *** [../bin/drone_stateestimation] Error 1
  make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/build'
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/drone_stateestimation.dir/all] Error 2
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/build'
  make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks/tum_ardrone/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rpserver/ros/rosbuild/stacks
```

The above error is actually a linking error. Just add

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev libblas-dev
```

Ok looks like it has built up!

PS: I don't know if it was useful but I added `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fpermissive")` to CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0